# Big O, Omega and Theta Exercises

Tags: asymptotics

i have a few exercises to do but i need someone to correct me if they can.
I am very new to the Big O notation so please forgive me for being too basic.

I need to represent everything under Θ.

T(n) = 10n + 2^(2*log n) -->
Answer= Θ(n)

T(n) = n^2.5 + n^log 4 -->
Answer= Θ(n^2.5)

T(n) = n log n + n^1/2 -->
Answer = Θ(log n)

Am I right? or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

In the third, both $n\ln n $ and $n^{1/2}$ are much bigger than $\ln n$. But your other two are correct.

Comment: Thanks so what's the answer for the third one?

Comment: which of the two terms is bigger?

Answer (score 0):

For the third one, to be explicit,
it is
$\Theta(n \ln n)$,
since that is larger that $n^{1/2}$.